# Can't add child's account to YouTube channel

Tags: youtube, google-account, youtube-channel, google-family-link

I have a YouTube channel under my (adult) account where my kid posts videos. I'd like to add him as a member of the channel, officially but when I try to add him, I get this message:

[image: "This email address cannot be used"]

I tried setting the permissions using the other method, via the Brand Account. In that case I didn't get an error when I invited him but the invitation email never showed up in his inbox.

Note that his account (probably obviously) is a child account, and he is a member of Google Family. I did try moving him up a tier in YouTube Family > Content Settings, but it didn't help.

I couldn't find any documentation indicating who is / is not allowed to be part of a channel. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If your child is under 13 (or applicable age in your country), they can watch YouTube with your supervision, but are **not allowed** to have a YouTube Channel. I have found that error and all that errors means that your child is under 13 (or applicable age in your country). It is also possible that your child is 13 or older (or applicable age in your country) but you see that error, that means your child hasn't Manage their own account and their account still managed by you (parent).

So, I recommend that you manage your child's YouTube Channel with your own Google Account, until your child turn 13 (or applicable age in your country), then if your child's channel is in Brand Account, you can transfer the channel to them (but you must wait 7 days from the time you invited your child) once they turn 13 (or applicable age in your country).

---

Editor Note: There is a specific official help center for this topic: [Youtube Kids Parental Guide](https://support.google.com/youtubekids)

Comment: @JoshM. Added a link to the Youtube Kids Parental Guide

Answer (score 0):

I know, it is late. I also experiencing the issue.

And I have found the answer:
https://parentzone.org.uk/article/what-if-my-child-wants-their-own-youtube-channel

> What are the rules? YouTube doesn’t allow children under the age of 13
> to create their own channels or accounts, and children between ages 13
> and 17 are only allowed to open them with parental permission.
>
> If your child is under 13, you should set up the channel yourself –
> and continue to manage the content they post and everything they do on
> it from that point on.
>
> All content has to be in line with YouTube’s Community Guidelines.
> This includes a specific section on Child Safety on YouTube.

So, if your child is below 13 years (as mine) then it is disallowed to own/manage/etc a youtube channel by him.

I am wondered Google is not indicating it at invite process.